# Angular 2 - Object properties are return as undefined but they exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having this problem. I'm working with Angular and calling an API to get an object that has other objects inside. The problem is that I can't access to those objects, as they are returned as undefined. However, logging them in the console (with Google Chrome), the objects are actually there.

These are the relevant fragments of my code:

**questionnaire.component.ts**

```
export class QuestionnaireComponent extends BaseComponent {

    questionnaires: Models.Survey.Rootobject;
    ...
    ngOnInit() {

        ...do stuff...

        Observable.forkJoin(this.service.getAllQuestionnaires())
        .subscribe(res => {

            this.questionnaires = res[0];

            console.log(this.questionnaires);
            console.log(res[0]);
            console.log(this.questionnaires.questionnaireItems);

            this.numberOfQuestionnaires = this.questionnaires.questionnaireItems.length;

            ...do more stuff...

        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**questionnaire.service.ts**

```
...code...

getAllQuestionnaires() {

    return this.http.get<Models.Survey.Rootobject>('/api/v1/xmlquestionnaires').map(res => res[0]);
}
```

**Survey.ts**

```
declare namespace Models.Survey {

    ...more interfaces...

    export interface QuestionnaireItem {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        order: string;
        description: string[];
        finalText: string[];
        questionGroups: QuestionGroup[];
        questions: Question[];
        toRandomize: string;
    }

    export interface Rootobject {
        questionnaireItems: QuestionnaireItem[];
    }

    export interface Wrapper {
        rootobject: Rootobject;
    }

}
```

And the results of the "console.log(x)" are these:

[image: Resultados logging]

*QuestionnaireItems* is in the object, but accessing directly to it will return undefined.

Do you know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your method `getAllQuestionnaires()` is returning a `Wrapper` object instead of `Rootobject`.

In such case it would be sufficient to add ".rootobject" to your method **EDIT: and fix type, maybe like this**:

```
getAllQuestionnaires() {
    return this.http
        .get<Models.Survey.Wrapper>('/api/v1/xmlquestionnaires')
        .map(res => res[0].rootobject);
}
```

Comment: I think it is returning a `Rootobject`, because doing that will show this error: http://imgur.com/a/YnCdH

Comment: Is the "http" a standard service provided by angular2? I haven't used it with explicit type definition like get<MyType>(...) so far and I'm a little bit surprised about it. Normally I use get(...).map(respone => response.json()).

Comment: Arg, can't believe this was the error. Thank you very much! I followed your answer changing the object I was getting to `get<Models.Survey.Wrapper>` and in the *component* changed this: `this.questionnaires = res[0]` to this: `this.questionnaires = res[0].rootobject`.

Comment: And no, the *http* service was a custom serviced that used the Angular one inside. I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

its normal returning value is undefined. JS is confused because you want to access array in array if you use it like this problem is going to solve i guess

i index in your case 1 to 3

```
console.log(this.questionnaries[i].questionnaireItems)
```

Comment: Did not work :( `this.questionnaires` is an object (in this case, a `Rootobject`, not an array). And if I try to access `res[0][1]` for example, it will cause an error as `res[0]` is still undefined.

Comment: sorry my bad :/